# Angular pm2 how to load outpudHashed main.8646asdasdas6d8468.js file when name changes every build?

Tags: angular, pm2

How to load `main.asdas68d4a6s8d468as4d.js` file with pm2 so it would load any file like :

```
main.asdas68d4a6s8d468as4d.js
main.aaaaa64684684sasdasda.js
main.xxxxx68d4a6as8d4a6ss8.js
```

Angular build with --outputhashing=all makes main.js file name different after each build, so I have to load it everytime from different name in my server. How do I achieve this with pm2 ?

**Normally i just use : `pm2 start dist/web/server/main.js`**

Comment: you can use `ng build --prod=true --outputHashing=none --namedChunks=false --vendorChunk=false` to generate the bundles without the hash: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: I need to use outpudHashing because i want to clear cache after each build

Comment: @Devla were you able to find a solution? Please share if you did.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea about pm2 and I don't know if work you create a .bat like

```
echo pm2 start >qqq.bat
dir /b main.*.js>>qqq.bat
qqq.bat
```